# Could a cacheing plugin cause css not to edit?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress theme previously coded by another developer. I had some trouble migrating it to another server because of a cache plugin called memcache and now I'm not able to remove a body background from this css file. The developer made two instances where he called a body background image in style.css and master.css. I changed the background even deleted the old one and its still not changing. I Cleared my cache several times even tried it on another machine. I checked it on developer tools and it shows up on 2 different style sheets both of them I changed only 1 is crossed out. If i uncheck that style in developer tools it removes it but I can't figure out why it's not changing. Could a cacheing system the previous developer installed be the issue here?

Comment: If you've tried it on multiple computers and cleared your cache multiple times then it's probably user error (sorry!) - use your dev tools to find out which line and on what style sheet you want to change. Locate that spot - remove it entirely (it won't show up crossed out in dev tools of done correctly, the style shouldn't show up at all). Then make sure you upload / update the css file.

Comment: yea that's weird cause I go there and its not there cause I removed it. but the style still shows up in dev tools and the background is still on the page. I actually deleted both style sheets clear my cache, reload and they are still there.

Comment: How are you editing the files? FTP or through WordPress?

Comment: I'm editing through FTP

Comment: Are you sure you're uploading to the correct spot? If you really want to be sure you can disable all your plugins to see if that helps.

Comment: I don't think this theme is getting it's files from my server. The style editor on developer tools shows a link to the stylesheet that isn't the stylesheet url I'm working with. I can't see the whole url but I could tell from what I can see that it isn't on my server.

Comment: I found the url which points to a 3rd party host zippykid or pressable. that has the exact copy of the theme I'm working on. Really weird....

Comment: @ng_07 You said that you were migrating servers. I'm guessing that the old server was hosted at pressable. There's probably a hard-coded file somewhere that's pointing to the old site.

Comment: yea that's what I thought too but I cant seem to find it. I even deleted the plugin files and it's still not working. I logged into their hosting and theres an option the purge cache but I dont wanna hit that because I'm not sure if it'll effect the current site.

Comment: @ng_07 Did you view the source? It should be really easy to see hard-coded files. You could probably just do a ctrl-f for ".com".

Comment: I got it fixed there was a muplugin causing it to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the cache or clearing it from the server. It is the style.css is cached with the server and pulling from there, with higher expirations dates and serving it away from querying the database on every visit. This is a common problem with any caching plugin for Wordpress.